# C# Winform Retrieving Formatted text from MySQL Database to Richtextbox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, richtextbox

I am attempting to retrieve the selected row data from a datagridview and display it in a RichTextBox.

There is no error message. It appears that when I click on a row it will only show the data like Title and it's ID and not the Content in the RichTextBox.

Here are some screenshots and the code I have used.

Below is the code:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

            string rtfText = this.rtxtinccon.Rtf.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
            btnPost.Enabled = true;
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dtvlist.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            #region strings

            lblincid.Text = row.Cells["IID"].Value.ToString();
            cbeid.Text = row.Cells["EID"].Value.ToString();
            txttitle.Text = row.Cells["Title"].Value.ToString();
            rtfText = row.Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();

            #endregion

        }
```

And here is the runtime

[image: Image of the app]

I use LONGTEXT utf8mb4_unicode_ci as a datatype.

Hope you could help me. I already searched all the possible answer but haven't found any solution.

Comment: Debug your code..

Comment: @reds what should I put or edit?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: @reds I want to display the content of my Description column which is a LONGTEXT utf8mb4_unicode_ci. I want to retrieve its format to my richtextbox when I clicked the row.

Comment: Please check [MCVE] guidnace on posting code, [edit] code in the post and also clarify what step (reading, setting to rich text, other) causing problems. As of now post look like "typographical error" as you seem to miss setting value of your rich text control.

Comment: Just asking, why downvoted? I just read and tried almost all of the possible answers that were asked and answered before but it just don't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are just getting the content from `RichTextBox` as string and made changes in that string. As string is immutable itself, your changes wouldn't be reflected in your `RichTextBox`. So, you need to assign your content again to your `RichTextBox` control.

You need to set text to your RtfTextBox control in following way :

```
this.rtxtinccon.Rtf = row.Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes. It says that the File Format is not valid.

Comment: That means, your content is not in Rtf format. You just need to simply use Text property of RichTextBox control

Comment: @JoshuaDelaCruz : For Rtf, you need to have formatted Rtf. But for Text, it will display as plain text

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
 RichTextBox1.Text = row.Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: what long text example?

Comment: Sorry seems like it is he's Richtextbox.

Comment: I would like to use the RTF instead of TEXT because it will not display it correctly

Comment: then go ahead do it.

Comment: Can you show what kind of text you want to put in RTF? sample text

Comment: Sample Stories
By Bruce Holland Rogers
Rogers is an award-winning writer (Pushcart Prize, two Nebula Awards.

Readers who don't know Bruce's work can read some sample short-shorts at the following sites:

"Little BrotherTM"
The Dead Boy at Your Window"
 Award for 2012)
"Word Problem"

Comment: When I use RTF, there is an error, but TEXT it hasn't. But the display text has this and it is not formatted. {
tf1ansiansicpg1252deff0deflang1033{fonttbl{f0fnilfcharset0 Segoe UI Light;}}
viewkind4uc1pardf0fs18 This story is an illustration of a fixed form as described

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The richtextbox display like this **{ tf1ansiansicpg1252deff0deflang1033{fonttbl{f0fnilfcharset0 Segoe UI Light;}} viewkind4uc1pardf0fs18**

Comment: what is the original text value?

Comment: It is a sample story copied from google and pasted it to my richtextbox. even when I typed it manually still the same

Answer (score 1):

Your content is not in `Rtf` format. For example add this code before `#endregion`:

```
this.rtxtinccon.Rtf = @"{\rtf\ansi This is some \b bold\b0 text.}"; // for example
```

Reference: [RichTextBox.Rtf Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx).

> **Remarks**: You can use this property to place RTF formatted text into the
>   control for display or to extract the text of the control with the
>   specified RTF formatting defined in the text of the control. This
>   property is typically used when you are assigning RTF text from
>   another RTF source, such as Microsoft Word or Windows WordPad, to the
>   control. If you change the RightToLeft property at run time, only raw
>   text without formatting is preserved. For the RTF codes, see "rich
>   text format (RTF) Specification, version 1.6" in the MSDN library.

Comment: It appears to be just a rtxtinccon.Text not RTF. No formatting

Comment: so I what am I going to type then if the code is only an example? Please help me, really need it badly. Thanks

Comment: @JoshuaDelaCruz, your content is not in Rtf format. Prepare you text in rtf format and write it in RichTextBox

Comment: I just typed it and it still like that. Maybe I should not make it like a LONGTEXT datatype?

Comment: @JoshuaDelaCruz, It's not LONGTEXT. From your code your data type is `string`, it is normal. But your text is not in Rtf format. If you wanna paste simple text use `Text` property of `RichTextBox`.  It will not be formatted.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is it. Thanks for your time! Really helped me a lot